# Joomla Jforms div classes issues

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a jforms forms with few checkboxes and I want to align them horizontally. I have created custom DIV class and assigned it to those checkboxes in the Jform settings. Checkboxes already the members of two another DIV classes. 
I have tried to align checkboxes then with **float:left**, nothing happens. 
**display:inline-block** seem to be does the trick but after I submit the form with following redirection to another page my browser return **Error-0:Frame not found in cellmap**. Seems to be there is a conflict at div classes formatting and I'm not able to figure out where is an issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have digged further and looks like narrowed a search. Seems to be there is an issue with DOMPDF library.